# ST_DWithin coordinate transforming one or both geometries

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system

I want to use the function as such

```
ST_DWithin(c.convex_hull, cp.geoJson, 20)
```

both arguments are geometries with EPSG 4326 with undefined SRID's but coordinate system is 4326, as I am told.

Should I use st_transform here? if so, should I use it on one, or both function arguments?

**Update** - I believe this might be the safest way (but I require guidance on this) -

```
ST_DWithin(st_transform(c.convex_hull,4326)::geography , st_transform(cp.geoJson,4326)::geography, 20)
```

Comment: If your data is 4326, the best is to change the column type to enforce it. Else, if you are sure there is nothing but 4326, you don't need to transform but just to set the SRID. At last, "no srid" is understood as 4326 when casting to geography. That being said, using geography has other implications that you should be aware of, such as using great circles instead of straight lines. From your other posts, it might be better to keep using the UTM zone.

Comment: You'd have to check the source to see what ST_Transform does when theSRID is undefined, but it is unwise to ever load data with an undefined SRID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safest and most performant way is

`alter table my_table alter column geom type geometry(<POINT,LINESTRING,MULTIPOLYGON,etc>,4326) using st_setsrid(geom,4326)`

after you have verified that the source data is, in fact, using 4326.

Then you can forget about using st_transform in your queries, which will destroy any indexes you have on the geometry that you're transforming on the fly.